# Extracting titles of articles deposited in pubmed from Pubmed IDs using bioentrez

Tags: biopython

I am trying to extract titles for some articles deposited in Pubmed using Pubmed IDs (that I have in a list called 'ids'). There are around 650K Pubmed IDs. The code seems to work fine and doesn't throw any errors. But the code extracts tiles only for a fraction of articles and not all.

Following is the code:

```
Entrez.email = "xyz@enginebio.com"

for i in range(0,len(ids),10000):

    if i%10000 == 0:   # for me to track the progress of the script
        print (i)

    idlist=ids[i:i+10000]
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=idlist, retmode="xml")

    try:
        record = Entrez.read(handle)
    except:
        continue

    title={}

    for j in range(len(record["PubmedArticle"])):

        pmid=record["PubmedArticle"][j]['MedlineCitation']['PMID'][:]
        if "Abstract" in record["PubmedArticle"][j]['MedlineCitation']['Article'].keys():
            title[pmid]=record["PubmedArticle"][j]['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

    # save article titles
    subfile='article_titles_'+str(i)+'.txt'
    ar = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(title, orient="index")
    ar.to_csv(subfile,sep="\t",header=None)
```

Any suggestions will be useful. Thanks

Comment: That `except: continue` could potentially hide some errors if the handle returned is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your example because I do not have your Pubmed ID list. It would be also interesting to know how many of the ~650K IDs you recover, it's not the same if you are recovering 639K titles (probably some of your IDs are simply missing), or 10K. I have tried a mini example myself and it does retrieve the titles. I think maybe some of the IDs are not valid. You could try to do smaller batches and also:

1. This `except: continue` will hide any problems that may have arisen from an empty handle (if the query result was empty). I would try to check the exceptions.
2. Throw a warning if `len(record["PubmedArticle"])` is smaller than your batch size. This way you can narrow down the IDs you may be missing.
3. You are only adding the title to your `title` dict if the registry has an `Abstract` field. Are you sure this is the case for all the records? The cases I tried it did apply but maybe not all entries have this.